# Cordova Local Notification Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova

I'd like schedule a new local notification after trigger the first notification, but it seems trigger event is not working. I'm trying on IOS device.

```
var alarmTime = new Date();
alarmTime.setSeconds(alarmTime.getSeconds() + 20);
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: "1",
    at: alarmTime,
    text: "Test",
    title: "Test",
    sound: PontualproFactory.isiOSDevice()?'file://beep.caf':'file://sound.mp3'
});

cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("trigger", function (notification) {
    alarmTime = new Date();
    alarmTime.setSeconds(alarmTime.getSeconds() + 20);
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: "2",
        at: alarmTime,
        text: "Test",
        title: "Test",
        sound: PontualproFactory.isiOSDevice()?'file://beep.caf':'file://sound.mp3'
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of alarmTime? AFAIk you can't schedule multiple notifications in iOS at the same time, but I'm not sure.

Comment: srry, I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

My open source library [**BlackTie.js**](https://www.github.com/divakarmanivel/blacktie) has a `notify` function that does exactly what you need!